# How to display all scores at the end without a loop?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to display my score at the end of a questionnaire however my way of doing it only displays the last score.

It would work if I were to put it in a loop, the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog however I only want it to display this once, at the end.

Here is my code.

```
//Main method

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printPlayerScore(playerName, playerAge, playerScore, playerCount));

//printPlayerScore method

public static String printPlayerScore(String playerName[], int playerAge[], int playerScore[], int playerCount) {
   String displayResult = "";

   for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
        displayResult += "\nName: " + playerName[i] + "\nAge: " + playerAge[i] + "\nScore: " +  playerScore[i] + "\n";
   }

   return displayResult;
}
```

Example run:

`Player1: 12`

`Player2: 12`

When it should be

`Player1: 10`

`Player2: 12`

I know I need to change the method to something else, but how else could I do it?

Full code: http://pastebin.com/NME8Dh7N

Comment: Why? It appears like it should work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It displays only the last score for all players. If Player1 got 5, and Player2 got 10, it will display 10 for both

Comment: Are you sure Player1 has a score of 10? Have you tried looking at it in the debugger or doing `System.out.println(playerScore[0])`? Is it possible you're not putting player scores in the array correctly?

Comment: The problem is probably in the way you are filling the arrays, not with the method.

Comment: try tp print the playerScore array before calling the method to see if you are having the right data.

Comment: I checked, and the scores are the same even though it displays the correct scores in my code before this. I will post my full program so you can have a look and help me.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NME8Dh7N

Comment: Please try the suggestions and update with a solution you have chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a screaming example of the benefits of [Object-Oriented Programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/). OOP will make this chunk of code easier to debug, read, and write. I'll write some quick code to explain this better (by no means is it perfect). Notice how we can easily create a nice output string using the properties of a `Player`. Create an array of `Player` objects, and pass it into your print method.

```
public class Player
{
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public int score;

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("\nName : %s\nAge: %d\nScore: %s\n", name, age, score);
    }
}

public static String printPlayerScore(Player[] players) 
{
   String displayResult = "";

   for(Player player : players)
   {
        displayResult += player.toString();
   }

   return displayResult;
}
```

Comment: Since you Override toString, how about `return Arrays.toString(players);`

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not code this problem the way you did as it's not OOP and just very confusing. However, here is something you can use so as to not totally break your code but fix your problem.

The main question you are trying to answer is why is the last score showing up. As others have stated, you are using one array for player scores. Here is hack to change your code to get it working:

```
        List<int[]> playerScoresList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
        {
            int playerScore[] = new int[1];
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is " + playerName[i] + "'s turn now!");

            checkQuestion(question, questionAnswer, userAnswer);

            System.out.println("Name: " + playerName[i] + " || Age: " + playerAge[i] + "\n\n ~~~~ Results ~~~~");
            System.out.println(printQuestionnaireResults(question, userAnswer) + " ~~~~ End of Results ~~~~\n");

            playerScore = calculatePlayerScore(userAnswer, playerScore, playerCount);
            // double playerScorePercentage = ((double)playerScore[i] / (double)question.length) * 100;
            double playerScorePercentage = ((double)playerScore[0] / (double)question.length) * 100;

            System.out.println(playerName[i] + " got " + playerScore[0] + " questions correct out of " + question.length + "! (" +
                    playerScorePercentage + "%)\n");

            playerScoresList.add(playerScore);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printPlayerScore(playerName, playerAge, playerScoresList, playerCount));
```

Other methods that need to be changed:

```
        public static int[] calculatePlayerScore(boolean userAnswer[], int playerScore[], int playerCount) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            playerScore[i] = 0;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < userAnswer.length; ii++) {
                if (userAnswer[ii]) {
                    playerScore[i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return playerScore;

    }
```

And:

```
        public static String printPlayerScore(String playerName[], int playerAge[], List<int[]> playerScore, int playerCount) {

        String displayResult = ""; // Maybe use StringBuilder

        for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
        {
            int[] score = playerScore.get(i);
            displayResult += "\nName: " + playerName[i] + "\nAge: " + playerAge[i] + "\nScore: " + score[0] + "\n";
        }

        return displayResult;
    }
```

Now, you will create a new array with one element each time for each user.

Please keep in mind this hack is provided such that there should be minimal change in your **current** code. You should seriously consider re-writing the entire program IMO. I've also commented out some other code as well just to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

According to your pastebin, you only have 1 array for storing question answers. Meaning the n+1 player is overwriting n player's answers.

You could either do a matrix (Array of Arrays), or the easier to read alternative, make a class for players and have that class manage player data, with the program having only a list of players. It will reduce the number of parameters in the function calls and allow for easy individualization of answers.

```
public class Player {
  private String name;
  private List<boolean> answers;
  private int playerId;
}
```

The matrix would work like this:

```
boolean answers[][] = new boolean[playerCount][questionCount];
```

That way, each player has a separate list of answers that independ from each other.

Then, all you need would be to get send each player as a parameter to the functions and read those as necessary.